# I want to align my images in such a way where 2 images come above the other 2 images using html as shown in the image with some text below every image

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to align my images in such a way where 2 images come above the other 2 images using HTML as shown in the image with some text below every image.

The image of Steve jobs in the above code is perfectly aligned but now I want the image of Tesla to be right beside it and some text below it. Then 2 more images will be added in the same manner right below those 2 images. Can someone please show me how to do that?

[image: WebPage similar to that]

Here is my html code:

```
<body style="background-color:#232122">
  <strong><h2 style="color:#FFFFFF"><i><center>We are comfortable being the geniuses behind the scenes <br/> but sometimes people want to know who we are</center></strong>
  </i>
  </h2>
  <hr/>

  <h2 style="background-color:#FAAE3D;color:#BF360C;border-radius:20px">
    <center>About</center>
  </h2>
  <p style="color:#BF360C;margin-left:3em;margin-right:5em;border:3px solid #FAAE3D;border-radius:20px;border-left:5px;border-right:5px;border-spacing:10px;padding:10px">Armour was developed by some of the most dashing, kick-ass and the smartest people on this planet (didnt even boast about it, you see!!) as a part of their final year project. But as we grew, amazing people like you hopped in the ride and our family
    grew bigger and bigger. We are basically a security-providing company. I know that is likely over-simplified but is still better than a long list of descriptors. We make Bluetooth-based doorlocks that run on Android platforms and provide an added
    layer of biometric security (I use these jargons so that some dumbshits feel like they are reading the orthodox "about-us" page, what i am really saying is we use fingerprints as an added security measure, thats it, folks!)</p>

  <h2 style="background-color:#80BD9E;color:#26382F;border-radius:20px">
    <center>Meet Team Awesome</center>
  </h2>
  <p style="color:#80BD9E;margin-left:3em;margin-right:5em;border:3px solid #80BD9E;border-radius:20px;border-left:5px;border-right:5px;border-spacing:10px;padding:10px"><img src="jobs.jpg" style="float:top;width:250px;height:200px"><strong><br>Steve Jobs<br>CEO<br></strong>
    <img src="tesla.jpg" style="float:top;width:250px;height:200px;"><strong><br>Nicola Tesla<br>COO</strong>
  </p>

  <hr/>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Armour-2082718525306755/" title="Redirect to facebook page"><img src="fb.png" style="width:50px;height:50px"></a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/Armour-2082718525306755/" title="Redirect to youtube page"><img src="youtube.png" style="width:50px;height:50px"></a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/Armour-2082718525306755/" title="Redirect to twitter page"><img src="twitter.png" style="width:50px;height:50px"></a>
</body>
```

Comment: there isnt any steve jobs or tesla in the provided images please be careful to provide appropriate and relevant code that you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

Place each image and corresponding text in a div, then position it using CSS

```
div.topleft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 200px;

}

div.topright {
    position: absolute;
    left: 230px;
    top: 200px;

}
```